# Select2: mix local and remote results

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to mix local and remote results with Select2 4.0.3. When it's opened it should display the local results only and once starting to type, look for remote results which are then mixed into the results.

While it's working in principle, there are a few issues I have not been able to address. A demo based on the Select2 Githup repo example is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PNZ7xgu7hTvW7TVaDxgK?p=preview

I mix in the local results in `processResults`. This function is only called after performing a remote search. If I don't set a `minimumInputLength`, it performs a search without a search term on opening. In my test I just set a bogus search query which returns no results but then I have a superfluous AJAX call.

If I set `minimumInputLength`, the `processResults` handler is not called before enough characters were entered.

Is there a neat way to make this all work and display the local results instantly and only perform a remote call when necessary and augment the results?